# how to do USART communication please tell me everything which should be taken care to do usart communication

Tags: stm32, avr, usart, cubemx, stm32cubemx

---

> I am Using Atollic and cubemx on ubuntu.

---

Comment: Ask the question on your native language SO site or ask someone to translate. I do not understand what you mean. Before you ask read : [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Please listen to P__J__ this is not a minimal reproducible example, ALSO transmit to receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question deserves a tutorial by its own, but in short you need to

1. Define the pins for both RX and TX
2. Define your protocol options [ baud rate, parity, crc..]
3. Calculate the prescaleers (USARTDIV) according to you src clock and baudrate
4. define whether or not you need interrupts for reception or transmission

Please take a look to the book **Mastering STM32 by Carmine Noviello**.
Also read the section of [STM32 user manual Page 785 chapter 27](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/59/b9/ba/7f/11/af/43/d5/CD00171190.pdf/files/CD00171190.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00171190.pdf)